# lambda expression for Consumer Interface with return type

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

The thing I don't quite understand is why java compiler allows a lambda expression such as `s -> s.isEmpty()` inside a consumer interface.

I have tried a lambda expression like `s -> s.isEmpty()` for a Consumer interface and it works without issue. Some other lambda expressions don't work because they return something, like `s -> s`.

```
Consumer<String> cons1 = s -> s.isEmpty();
cons1.accept("abc");
```

compiles and executes without issue.

So the problem I have is that I thought lambda expressions such as `s -> s.isEmpty()` were always equivalent to `s -> {return s.isEmpty()};` and so I was expecting the compiler to give me an error because you cannot return a `boolean` (or any other type) from a Consumer Interface.
Obviously the compiler is translating the lambda expression into a method were there is no return statement and the method `isEmpty()` is simply being called without actually returning the value. 
So the question is When is the return added to the body of the lambda expression? This is so I can know when the compiler will give a compiler error and why.

Thank you very much and sorry if I don't explain myself well enough, I am new here.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The method `isEmpty()` is called when the `Consumer` object is used. However, the return value of `isEmpty()` isn't used and is simply ignored.

Comment: That is because a method invocation expression can discard the return type if that'll make it compatible with the target type. So `s -> s.isEmpty()` is equivalent to either `s -> { return s.isEmpty(); }` or `s -> { s.isEmpty(); return; }`

Comment: `s.isEmpty()` is a statement, `s` is not.

Comment: If this was not allowed, you wouldn't be able to use `set.add` as a consumer either, because that would ignore the return type. You're allowed to ignore the return type.

Comment: You could also do `Consumer<String> cons1 = String::isEmpty;`, but the return keyword is not added... The accept method has a void return type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the *single abstract method* defined within the `FunctionalInterface` defines the way the lambda is inferred. For example, the `Consumer<String>` in the example shared could be represented as an anonymous class such as:

```
// Consumer<String> consumer = s -> s.isEmpty();
Consumer<String> consumer = new Consumer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(String s) {
        s.isEmpty(); // treated as void here 
    }
};
```

The same lambda expression when represented as a `Predicate<String>` could be converted to an anonymous class such as:

```
// Predicate<String> predicate = s -> s.isEmpty();
Predicate<String> predicate = new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(String s) {
        return s.isEmpty(); // returns boolean here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It is clearly defined in [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2), If the body of a lambda is a statement expression, result will be discarded if return type is void

## 15.27.3. Type of a Lambda Expression

**If the body of a lambda is a statement expression (that is, an expression that would be allowed to stand alone as a statement), it is compatible with a void-producing function type; any result is simply discarded. So, for example, both of the following are legal:**

```
 //Predicate has a boolean result
   Predicate<String> p = s -> list.add(s);

// Consumer has a void result
   Consumer<String> c = s -> list.add(s);
```

> Generally speaking, a lambda of the form `() -> expr`, where expr is a statement expression, is interpreted as either `() -> { return expr; }` or `() -> { expr; }`, depending on the target type.